# How to implement Oauth authentication in woocommerce

Tags: oauth, woocommerce

I created Application on Google, Facebook and LinkedIn and having API Key and Secret Key with me. But not experience how to Use that for Login.

I like to Use Oauth for login and checkout for products. 
Store Logged-In public data into database.

I am looking for help/ guidence how to do this.

Looking for you all kind support.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the [WooCommerce Social Plugin](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/woocommerce-social-login-create-social-apps/) can handle that for you, though it's not free (currently $79/year).

From their site:

> The plugin currently supports login with these platforms: WooCommerce
>   Facebook Login, WooCommerce Twitter Login, WooCommerce Google Login,
>   WooCommerce Amazon Login, WooCommerce LinkedIn Login, WooCommerce PayPal
>   Login, WooCommerce Instagram Login